# Remove all data but not formula in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to re use some excel 2013 sheets, they are annual household expenditure, etc. I wish to remove the existing data, but leave the formulas and preferably column header texts and also leave formats as is.Can someone suggest if there is a quick way to strip out the now old data without having to rebuild the existing sheets. This is in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
Sub kleanUP()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    rng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Run it on each sheet you want to cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Excel will not be able to distinguish between constants that are headers and constants that are not headers. If your headers are in row 1 only, then Gary's code will work, but if they are not, you can select all cells below your headers, then hit F5, click Special, tick "Constants" and hit OK. Then hit the Delete key on your keyboard.